# How many dependencies to I need to list in nested require calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs

I have a question. Say I have a module like the following :

```
define(['jquery', 'aModule', 'anotherModule'], function () {
    ....
}
```

Lets say I assign the above module the name 'myModule' in my requirejs config file.

In some other file I do this:

```
require(['myConfigFile'], function () {
    require['myModule'], function(module) {
    }
}
```

Do I need to require all the modules that are part of the 'myModule' definition in my nested require statement as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

RequireJs will 'translate' that to `'jquery', 'aModule', 'anotherModule'`.

In other words, it will first load modules 'jquery', 'aModule', 'anotherModule' before loading 'myModule'

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to require all the modules that are part of the 'myModule' definition in my nested require statement as well?

No, you don't. If you are asking this question, you probably do not understand the purpose of the nested `require` calls. The reason in some cases you want to nest `require` calls to load a configuration first and then a module is that this is *one* way to make sure your configuration is loaded *before* you try to load any of the "actual" modules of your application. The code in your question will:

1. Load `myConfigFile` and execute it. Presumably, this file contains only a call to `require.config`.
2. Load `myModule`, determine its dependencies, load the dependencies `jquery`, `aModule`, `anotherModule`, load the dependencies' dependencies, etc. then execute your module.

Typically people arrive at the nested `require` workaround after they've tried a `myModule` module which would look like this:

```
define(['myConfigFile', 'jquery', 'aModule', 'anotherModule'], ...
```

There are many problems with this:

1. If the configuration is needed to find `myModule`, then loading `myModule` will fail.
2. Even if `myModule` can be found without the configuration, if any of `jquery`, `aModule`, `anotherModule` *or their dependencies* require the configuration so that they can be found or properly loaded, then loading `myModule` will fail.

Rather than nest `require` calls like this, I prefer to have my configuration loaded with a `script` element just after RequireJS is loaded.